# AspNet TagHelper ViewImport WhiteScreen

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

As said in many tutorials I added a ViewImport.cshtml file. To this file I added the following code:

`@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"`
And inside of the project.json I added the following two lines:

`"Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta4"
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta7"`

Every time I run it, I am getting a white screen.
Thanks if someone can help me!

Comment: What do you have in your specific view ?

Comment: What do you mean with my specific view? Sorry I am petty new to AspNet. My goal is to have a link with Asp because I don't want to append the ~ sign at the front of the href link. But as I inspected it, the program doesn't load because of the ViewImport.

Comment: When are you getting the white screen ? Which page you are trying to access ? What is the code you have for that view ?

Comment: I am trying to access the index page, but all pages are white. It is definitely a problem with the ViewImport, because when I remove the ViewImport page, then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working on my own. It was a pretty simple, but heavy error which caused my application not to load.

[image]

I accidently didn't use the folder and used this blue icon thing instead, but that is the worng thing.
I should have used the folder in order to get it working.